# How to use operator '??' on type of float

Tags: c#

I'm getting the error:

> `Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'float' and 'float'`

I'm trying to set `'var result'` **if** the `float` property in the list is not empty or null. **If** it is null then use the default `float` value of `0.0f`.

The code I'm receiving the error on is like this:

```
var result = calculationsList.Where(x => x.SomeValue == 123).FirstOrDefault().Value ?? 0.0f;
```

I've also tried:

```
var tVal = calculationsList.Where(x => x.SomeValue == 123).FirstOrDefault().Value;
var result = tVal != null ? tVal : 0.0f;
```

Comment: @gunr2171 I've fixed the typo. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an excerpt from the [official documentation on the `??` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator):

> In C# 7.3 and earlier, the type of the left-hand operand of the ?? operator must be either a reference type or a nullable value type. Beginning with C# 8.0, that requirement is replaced with the following: the type of the left-hand operand of the ?? and ??= operators cannot be a non-nullable value type.

In other words, the left side of the operator must be something that is actually allowed to be `null`. The `float` type does not meet that requirement, but `float?` would meet this requirement.

> I'm trying to set 'var result' if the float property in the list is not empty or null.

**There's no such thing as an empty or null float!** It is a *value type*, and value types are never `null`.

Comment: "It is a value type, and value types are never null." - meant constructively, not pedantic (although it may seem it), but: `float?` is a value type, and can be `null` (for a language-specific definition of `null` that involve the `null` keyword). I totally agree that finding precise words that are understandable: is not easy here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `Value`

```cs
var result = calculationsList.Where(x => x.SomeValue == 123).FirstOrDefault() ?? 0.0f;
```

But if you just want to get `0`, this is anyway the default value of a `float`, so you can do this:

```cs
var result = calculationsList.Where(x => x.SomeValue == 123).FirstOrDefault().GetValueOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type '`float`' and
> '`float`'

It implies that the resulting type is of `float`, but `Nullable<float>` which is `float?`